# How can I embed a simple, type JSON, web service into my website using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble trying to work out how to embed a very simple web service into my website. The url of the web service is `example.com/movie-trivia.php`.
It simply displays a randomly generated JSON type string such as:

```
{"movie-trivia":"For its American release, the first 20 minutes of  Trainspotting had to be re-dubbed to make the Scottish accents more intelligible."}
```

I need to embed this on one of my web pages where every time the page is refreshed, one of the many randomly generated movie trivia's from the source are displayed. Just to add, every time the source URL page is refreshed it only displays one random trivia every time, which is what i wish to do.

I am new to web development technologies so if someone could be so kind and provide me a solution of how to directly implement this into one of my pages.

Comment: Stack Overflow is geared towards helping you debug your programming code. It looks like you are asking a general question about what technology to use which will result in opinionated answers that don't give a concrete answer which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is Ajax. Google will help.

Comment: The URL specified in the question does not appear to be a web service or return any data. Yet, have a look at sample code at [CineWorld](https://www.cineworld.co.uk/developer/api/cinemas) which demonstrates how to use their service.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. This helped me a lot to understand how to do this the javascript way. Unfortunately it didnt work for me so I turned to php and finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the question using a PHP solution.

```
<?php

# A HTTP GET request

$url = 'http://www.example.com/movie-trivia.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;

?>
```

The solution displays the dynamic contents of the web-service. All I have to do is decode the JSON output into text without the key/value structure.

Thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in pure JavaScript but it's less code in jQuery. In your caller page you will need a place to show the text, for example:

```
<span id="trivia"></span>
```

Then you can write some simple jQuery to get the JSON from your PGP and display it on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('/movie-trivia.php').done(function(data) {
    $("#trivia").text(data.movie-trivia);
  });
});
```

This is an [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), so you must be on the same domain, otherwise you will have to deal with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).